# How do we use "where" as a conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

> The elements of the second column are called the alkali earth metals.
> Like the alkali metals, these are relatively soft metals that react
> with water to liberate hydrogen gas. But **where the alkali metals
> react explosively, the alkali earths are tamer**—they react slowly
> enough that the hydrogen does not spontaneously ignite, allowing
> calcium (20), for example, to be used in portable hydrogen generators.

From "Elements: A Visual Exploration of Every Known Atom in the Universe" by Theodore Gray (2012)

In the text above, does "where" mean "while or "in situations that"?

Comment: Modern grammar classifies "where" as a preposition that (in this case) takes a declarative content clause as complement. This "where" has been bleached of the basic locative meaning: here it indicates contrast, like "whereas".

Comment: It is better not to attach images of text. You should type the actual text in your question. Also you should say where the text comes from.

Comment: Yes, "where", "while", "in situations that" and "under conditions that" are all reasonable synonyms in this context.  No, it isn't equivalent to "but".  If it were, the two wouldn't appear together in the model.

Comment: where here = when

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't that a typo of 'while' or 'whereas'? I've never seen 'where' used like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can you cite any source that explains where means whereas?

Comment: In this case, ‘where’ has nothing to do with a place/a location.
You could replace it with ‘while’;’whereas’

Answer (score 1):

In the cited context, ***where*** is equivalent to ***whereas, although, but,...*** It's a *contrastive* conjunction, joining together two assertions that superficially appear incompatible / different in some way. *Alkali metals explode, **but** alkali earths don't*, which can be stylistically resequenced to ***Where[as]** alkali metals explode, alkali earths don't.*

Note that ***where*** in such contexts doesn't really have anything to do with actual locations or situations. Obviously not all alkali metals always explode in all circumstances, or we'd never be able to find or use them, but the cited text doesn't contain any allusion to specific circumstances where alkali metals explode. The same construction can be used of statements that are *continuously* "true", such as ***Where[as]** the Sun shines by its own light, we can only see the Moon because it reflects light.*

I think it's a little bit "stylised, affected" to use ***where*** (or indeed ***when***) instead of ***whereas***, but I don't think the usage is all that uncommon. The relevant definition in the full OED is II-12b: *In adversative sense: **While on the contrary** = **when** adverb (defn 9b), **whereas** adverb and conjunction (defn 3).*

Comment: If you remove all your comments, I will upvote this answer.